# Set UI elements after read firebase kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, mvvm, google-cloud-firestore, viewmodel

I am trying to read a document from a database in firebase and show the info at the UI. Any idea why is it not working?

Viewmodel:

```
var leid =  MediatorLiveData<Gas>()

init {
        initializeDocument()
    }

    fun initializeDocument(){
        mFirestore?.collection("expenditures")?.document("ASfavaftaseacdadf")?.get()?.addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                    if (document != null) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.data}")
                        var gastl = document.toObject<Gas>()!!
                        leid.value=gastl
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG", "No such document")
                    }
                }
                ?.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    Log.d("TAG", "get failed with ", exception)
                }
    }
```

After that, I use databinding for the UI. When I try to execute the code, I dont get any log or anything; It is like the function never execute.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The most obvious explanation would be that something evaluates to `null`. So you should begin by checking that.

Comment: Is `Log.d("TAG", "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.data}")` printing something out?

Comment: Nothing at all. If I try with debugger see what is going on, nothing inside the function is executed.

Comment: It is not null, I am sure of that. I even though, it does not print no such document or error.